# "{Not to sing my own praise} but I was a good-looking young lady", is this correct?

Tags: idioms-in-context

I came across the following sentence:

> Back then, there were many boys chasing me. **Not to sing my own
> praise** but I was a good-looking young lady.

Is "not to sing my own praise" correct use of the idiom "to sing someone's praises"?

Comment: It's one way to 'apologise for' a statement praising yourself. For some others, see [this post](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/279466/expression-to-introduce-an-immodest-statement/279484)

Comment: I could find no instances of **sing one's own praise** in the singular, nor is it idiomatic.

Comment: Yes, it's usually sing one's own **praises**.